# to prove $G/N$ = $(G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_1, G_2$ be sub groups of $G$ such that $G/N$, $(G_1/N_1)$ and $(G_2/N_2)$ are well defined. Also, $N_1, N_2 \leq N$. \ Need to prove: $G/N$ = $(G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2)$\ 
I have the following information at hand.\
1)I know that any element g in $G$ is congruent modulo N to $g_1g_2$ where each $g_i$ $\in$ $G_i$. i.e., $g \sim g_1g_2$ means $gN = g_1g_2N$\
2)Also, $N_i = G_i \cap N$ for i=1,2.\
3)Don't know if this would be useful. $G_1\cap G_2$ = $<k>$ for some $k$ $\in$ $G$.

Comment: What you need to prove does not seem to make sense. Those two quotients are not subgroups of $G/N$ in general.

Comment: And the product $(G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2)$ does not make sense in general.

Comment: In this case, $(G_1/N_1)$ and $(G_2/N_2)$ are sub groups of $(G/N)$ in the sense that there exists an injective homomorphism from either quotient groups to $(G/N)$. I missed to pass on this information.